# Unable to exchange hive partition using spark sql even after using enableHiveSupport()

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to push incremental data into a base hive table. To do that, I prepared the data in my staging database and stored it in a table with exact ddl of my base table. In order to move the data from staging to base, I am trying the "Exchange partition" on the hive table from spark.sql as below.

```
Alter table base.basetable drop partition (vehicle='BIKE');
ALTER TABLE base.basetable EXCHANGE PARTITION (vehicle='BIKE') WITH TABLE staging.stagingtable;
```

But I see the exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
Operation not allowed: ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION(line 1, pos 0)
== SQL ==
ALTER TABLE base.basetable (vehicle='BIKE') WITH TABLE staging.stagingtable
^^^
```

This looks like spark sql doesn't support "Exchange partition" even though I have set `enableHiveSupport()` in my program:

```
val spark  = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").getOrCreate()
```

Shouldn't `enableHiveSupport()` give me all support & access for Hive querying ?

I can do `insert overwrite base.basetable partition(vehicle) select * from staging.stagingtable where vehicle='BIKE'`

Some of our tables have huge data and if the feature "Exchange partition" doesn't work in spark sql. 
Could anyone let me know how can I exchange the partition in this case ?

Comment: `how can I exchange the partition in this case` - how about executing hive query instead of spark? (via beeline for example)

Comment: My entire program is written in spark. Any suggestions in this case ?

Comment: this should not be a problem, you can execute hive command from scala (JDBC  /plain bash command). as said in the answer below - you cannot do this with Spark.

Comment: for example: `import sys.process._; Seq("hive", "-e", "alter table...") !!`

Comment: @shay__ How about I write a plain old scala-jdbc class that connects to Hive using its connection props. Then Drop & Exchange the partition ? Is it what you are suggesting ?

Comment: Exactly. That, or executing hive command via plain bash as above. JDBC is probably the 'right' way to do that.

Comment: That means the answer to the question is correct.

Comment: Any way around you found?

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the answer. Such operations are NOT supported via spark sql.

Comment: Yes Thebluephantom. I understood that after I saw the job log. My question was how can I get past that ? I have written the entire code in spark. Hence I am trying to look if there is any other way to merge the final data into my base tables.

Comment: I answered the title in fact. Linux script may be. DF writer as using Spark.